# Animating class toggle/element swap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a function that swaps a "Menu" button with a "Close" button when clicked (hiding one div and displaying another), and vice versa. I'm struggling to add an animation to the toggle of each swap.

This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#menu-button').toggleClass('inactive', 1000);
    $('#close-button').toggleClass('inactive', 1000).toggleClass('active', 1000);
  });

  $('.close-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('#close-button').toggleClass('active').toggleClass('inactive', 1000);
    $('#menu-button').toggleClass('inactive', 1000).toggleClass('active', 1000);
  });
});
```

I've also tried `fadeIn`/`fadeOut`/`fadeToggle` instead of `toggleClass` to no avail. The problem with `fadeToggle` is that both elements briefly appear at the same time, and there's still no fade animation. Is there a better way to program this?

Answer (score 1):

`toggleClass()` doesn't allow animation. The second argument is not the time. See the docs:

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

I guess the best for you would be CSS transition:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

If you don't want to use transition, that would do the thing:

```
  $('#menu-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#menu-button').hide();
    $('#close-button').fadeIn();
  });

  $('.close-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('#close-button').hide();
    $('#menu-button').fadeIn();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').on('click', function() {
    $('#button1').hide();
    $('#button2').show().addClass('toggle');
  });
   $('#button2').on('click', function() {
    $('#button2').hide();
    $('#button1').show().addClass('toggle');
   
  });

  
    
});
```

```css
#button2
{
  display:none;
}
.button.toggle
{
    opacity: 1;
 animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1" class="button" >button1</button>
<button id="button2" class="button" >button2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use `toggleClass`, you must accompany it with a CSS transition in your stylesheet. Otherwise, the element will simply disappear, as `toggleClass` does not provide animation by itself.

A CSS transition would be simple to add to your stylesheet, all that would be necessary would be to place these properties on the rule for your class:

```
transition-property: all;
transition-duration: 0.5s; /* or however long you need it to be */
```

Remember that properties such as `display` cannot be animated, so you must control the appearance using a property such as `opacity`, which can be animated because it is a number.